# Finding an appropriate function to verify an equation involving a convolution.

Tags: real-analysis, functional-analysis, reference-request

This question is more a reference request, I have never learnt a method (other than by visual inspection) to solve "convolution equations" and wish to know how they are usually dealt with, formally:

Given a real valued function $h$ and a real valued function $f$ what is the mathematical procedure to find a function $g$ s.t.

$$h(t) = \int_{- \infty}^{\infty} f(t- \tau) g(\tau) \ d \tau$$

Comment: @drhab so I try various functions $g$ arbitrarily until one satisfies the equation?

Comment: Sorry, my former comment is wrong (I will delete it). I did not read you question carefully and thought you would be after finding $h$ on base of $f$ and $g$.

Comment: Use Fourier transforms and inversion formula, if that works in your example.